# How to use mapStateToProp in react redux

Tags: react-redux

I am creating search function, as a request I have to use `mapStateToProps` to get the data, how should I do in this file?

This is my code for that

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useDebounce from "../../custom-hook/index";
import "../Search/index.css";

function Search() {

  // State and setter for search term
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  // State and setter for search results
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  // State for search status (whether there is a pending API request)
  const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

  // Run every 5ms
  const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(searchTerm, 500);

  // Here's where the API call happens
  // We use useEffect since this is an asynchronous action
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Make sure we have a value (user has entered something in input)
      if (debouncedSearchTerm) {
        // Set isSearching state
        setIsSearching(true);
        // Fire off our API call
        searchCharacters(debouncedSearchTerm).then(results => {
          // Set back to false since request finished
          setIsSearching(false);
          // Set results state
          setResults(results);
        });
      } else {
        setResults([]);
      }
    },
    // This is the useEffect input array
    [debouncedSearchTerm]
  );

  // Pretty standard UI with search input and results
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Search..."
        className="search"
        onChange={e => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
      />

      {isSearching && <div>Searching ...</div>}

      {results.map(result => (
        <div key={result.id}>
          <h4>{result.title}</h4>
          <img
            src={`${result.thumbnail.path}/portrait_incredible.${
              result.thumbnail.extension}`}
            alt="something"
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
 // API search function
    function searchCharacters(search) {
      console.log(search);
   }
    
    export default Search;
```

As my code above, you can see that in return I have **`isSearching`** fucntion, it set by useState, but now I don't do like that, I have to set mapSateToProp to get prop from store

Please help me for this **thank you so much**

Comment: why do you need it to be  separated to two different components?

Comment: Because I have to use mapStateToProp, as a request I have to separate into two different components. That is my mentor request. Can you help me? I don't understand about this. Or if you can, no need to separate into two different components

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is taken from [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) documentation. You should import `connect` function form this library and then wrap your component.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { todos } = state
  return { todoList: todos.allIds }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
```

**Updated:**

Since you are using hooks [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) might work better for you.

Comment: I know to do like that, but how can I apply in Search function

Comment: Once you connect the `Search` component you can take data selected in `mapStateToProps` from its `props`. Could you explain, please, what do you mean, do you already have some reducer?

Comment: @Kite updated my answer to work with hooks. It will be useful If you tell me how does your reducer look like and which data should be selected form a store.

Comment: mapStateToProps there is no store for my searching, I will create mock data for that. There is no reducer, I mean I will create mock data for that example. Can you help me with this

Comment: Hm, usually in React community `mapStateToProps` means a function which used to select data form a Redux store, this data will be passed as props to React component. First of all you need to understand what do you need to do, which problem to solve. Probably if you can share we me a task description provided by your mentor I can help to move in the right direction.